# codeigniter, join table properties overrides other properties

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a project using codeigniter 3 and I have a following query

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("questions");
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = questions.user_id');
$this->db->where('article_id', $articleId);
$this->db->order_by('questions.id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();

// query
// SELECT * FROM `questions` JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `questions`.`user_id` WHERE `article_id` = 18 ORDER BY `questions`.`id` DESC
```

Currently, the id property from users table overrides the questions id one. The question's id is crucial.

I worry, I will have to write a custom query, which I am not really good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this as follow:

```
$this->db->select("*, questions.id as question_id");
```

It's obvious that properties with the same name will be overriden. That's why you should assign to them 'unique' names in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically mention the ids with alies like -

```
$this->db->select("questions.id as question_id, users.id as user_id, questions.*, users.*");
$this->db->from("questions");
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = questions.user_id');
$this->db->where('article_id', $articleId);
$this->db->order_by('questions.id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

This will give you specific columns named with question_id, user_id, questions table's all columns, users table's all columns

Or another better solution to use specific column names in select with alies if required.